# Spring 3.1 and Oracle Audit Trail: Providing application data to triggers

Tags: spring, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

**Problem Parameters**:

1. Spring 3.1
2. Oracle 11.2.0.3
3. Glassfish 2.1 Application Server, providing a JDBC connection pool.

**Problem Description**:

I am retrofitting user auditing in an existing set of administrative applications for adding, editing and deleting customer users.  I need to store the ID of the administrative user in audit records created by Oracle triggers associated with a number of tables. I want to make the administrative user Id accessible to the triggers by setting the Oracle CLIENT_IDENTIFIER attribute on each a connection retrieved from the connection pool before a database operation and then clear the attribute after the database operation.  I have something that works, but I don't really like the way it is done.

**The Question:**

Is there a way to access connections so an Oracle context attribute can be set before and after a database operation?  Maybe some kind of listener responding to an event?

I have looked at:

1. A million web pages (OK maybe that's an exaggeration, but I've googled for a three or four hours).
2. Using DataSourceUtils to get connections.  This would work, but I really don't want to manage the connections, I just want to intercept them on the way in and out of the pool to set the CLIENT_IDENTIFIER attribute value.
3. Overriding the getConnection method of the datasource.  Since this gets called somewhere inside the JdbcTemplate, I can't get the application data to the method.

I'm hoping that the Spring and/or Oracle Gurus will say "Well it's obvious and the answer is ... " without having to hack through my implementation, but here it is anyway. If nothing else, this does work in case someone is looking for an idea.

**My Implementation:**

All database operations are done using a JdbcOperations reference to a JdbcTemplate object injected into a Dao.  The add, edit and delete operation use the JdbcOperations query method, passing either a PreparedStatementCreator or a BatchPreparedStatementSetter.  I access the java.sql.Connection object provided by the application server connection pool in the callback methods for these objects (createPreparedStatement or setValues) to set the CLIENT_IDENTIFIER attribute.

applicationContext.xml datasource configuration:

```
<!-- Setup the datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/IpOneDatabasePool"/>
</bean>

<!-- Setup the transaction manager -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!-- Associate the transaction manager with objects that must be managed. -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="userDaoOperation" expression="execution(* com.myCompany.IpOne.dao.UserDaoImpl.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userDaoOperation"/>
</aop:config>

<!-- Bean providing access to the various prepared statement objects -->
<bean id="daoHelperFactory" class="com.myCompany.IpOne.dao.DaoHelperFactoryImpl" />

<!--  Bean that allows setting of the client identifier for the audit trail -->  
<bean id="databaseContextEditor" class="com.myCompany.IpOne.dao.OracleDatabaseContextEditor" />

<!-- Dao that manages persistence of User objects -->
<bean id="userDao" class="com.myCompany.IpOne.dao.UserDaoImpl" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="licenseDao" ref="licenseDao"/>
    <property name="appPropertyManager" ref="appPropertyManager"/>
    <property name="maximumLicensesPerUserKey" value="max_licences_per_user"/>
    <property name="daoHelperFactory" ref="daoHelperFactory"/>
</bean>
```

This is the user Dao interface

```
public interface UserDao {

    void addUser(User newUser,String adminUserId);

}
```

This is the user Dao class

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

    private JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcOperations = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void addUser(User newUser,String adminUserId) {

        PreparedStatementCreator insertUserStatement = 
            this.daoHelperFactory.getInsertUserStatement(newUser,adminUserId);

        KeyHolder keyHolder = this.daoHelperFactory.getKeyHolder();
        this.jdbcOperations.update(insertUserStatement, keyHolder);
        newUser.setUserId(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());

    }

}
```

This class provides access to the application context.

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private static ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
       return ctx;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {

        this.ctx = ctx;

    }

}
```

Interface for classes that provides various objects used by the Dao.

```
public interface DaoHelperFactory {

    PreparedStatementCreator getInsertUserStatement(User user,String adminUserId);   
    KeyHolder getKeyHolder();

}
```

This class is just a factory for PreparedStatementCreator and BatchPreparedStatementSetter objects and other objects used by the Dao.  I've changed it to provide the object that actually sets the database context attribute to the various objects being returned.

```
public class DaoHelperFactoryImpl implements DaoHelperFactory{

    private DatabaseContextEditor getDatabaseContextEditor(){

        ApplicationContext appContext = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseContextEditor databaseContextEditor = (DatabaseContextEditor) appContext.getBean("databaseContextEditor");

        return databaseContextEditor;

     }

    public KeyHolder getKeyHolder(){

        return new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    }

    public PreparedStatementCreator getInsertUserStatement(User user,String adminUserId){

        InsertUser insertUser = new InsertUser(user,adminUserId);
        insertUser.setDatabaseContextEditor(getDatabaseContextEditor());

        return insertUser;

    }

}
```

This is the interface for classes that set the database context

```
public interface DatabaseContextEditor {

    public DatabaseContextEditor getInstance();
    public  void setClientIdentifier(Connection connection,String clientIdentifier)        throws SQLException;

}
```

This is class which does that for Oracle

```
public class OracleDatabaseContextEditor implements DatabaseContextEditor{


    public void setClientIdentifier(Connection connection,String clientIdentifier) throws SQLException{

        OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor extractor = new OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor();

        oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection oracleConnection = null;

        if(!(connection instanceof oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection))
            oracleConnection = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) extractor.getNativeConnection(connection);
        else
            oracleConnection = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)connection;

        String[] metrics = new String[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_STATE_INDEX_MAX];
        metrics[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_CLIENTID_INDEX]=clientIdentifier;
        oracleConnection.setEndToEndMetrics(metrics,(short)0);

}

    public DatabaseContextEditor getInstance(){

        return new OracleDatabaseContextEditor();

    }
}
```

This class is the PreparedStatementCreator for adding a User

```
public class InsertUser implements PreparedStatementCreator {

     User insertUser;

    /** This is the admin user Id I need to store */
    String adminUserId;

    private final String SQL = "INSERT INTO SC_USR (" +
    "USR_ID, USR_SSO_NAME, USR_PH_NO, USR_SIP_NAME," +
    "USR_SIP_PSWD, USR_SIP_DISP_NAME, USR_SIP_DOMAIN, USR_SIP_PROXY," +
    " USR_CREATED_BY, USR_CREATED_DATETIME) " +
    "VALUES (SEQ_SC_USR_ID.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSTIMESTAMP)";

    private final String GENERATED_COLUMNS[] = {"USR_ID"};

    /** Object that provides functionality for setting values in the database context */
    private DatabaseContextEditor databaseContextEditor;


    public InsertUser(User user,String adminUserId){

        this.insertUser = user;
        this.adminUserId = adminUserId;

    }

    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

        this.databaseContextEditor.setClientIdentifier(connection, adminUserId);

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement =      connection.prepareStatement(SQL,GENERATED_COLUMNS);
        int i=1;
        preparedStatement.setString(i++,this.insertUser.getSsoName());
        preparedStatement.setString(i++,this.insertUser.getPhoneNumber());
        preparedStatement.setString(i++,this.insertUser.getSipName());
        preparedStatement.setString(i++,this.insertUser.getSipPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(i++,this.insertUser.getSipDisplayName());
        preparedStatement.setString(i++,this.insertUser.getSipDomain());
        preparedStatement.setString(i++,this.insertUser.getSipProxy());
        preparedStatement.setString(i++,this.insertUser.getCreatedBy().name());


        return preparedStatement;

    }

    public void setDatabaseContextEditor(DatabaseContextEditor databaseContextEditor) {
        this.databaseContextEditor = databaseContextEditor;
    }
}
```

There are "AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE" triggers on each table I want to audit.  Each table has a corresponding audit table. They extract the CLIENT_IDENTIFIER from the context and insert a row in the appropriate audit table.  This is a sample.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IPONE_DEV_USER.SC_USR$AUDTRG
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON IPONE_DEV_USER.SC_USR 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
v_operation VARCHAR2(10) := NULL;
v_admin_user_id VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN 

    v_admin_user_id := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CLIENT_IDENTIFIER');
    IF INSERTING THEN 
       v_operation := 'INS'; 
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN 
       v_operation := 'UPD'; 
    ELSE 
       v_operation := 'DEL'; 
    END IF; 

IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN

   INSERT INTO SC_USR$AUD (
USR_ID,
USR_SSO_NAME,
USR_PH_NO,
USR_SOME_VALUE1,
USR_SOME_VALUE2,
USR_SOME_VALUE3,
USR_SOME_VALUE4,
USR_CREATED_BY,
USR_SOME_VALUE5,
USR_SOME_VALUE6,
aud_action,aud_timestamp,aud_user) VALUES (
:new.USR_ID,
:new.USR_SSO_NAME,
:new.USR_PH_NO,
:new.USR_SOME_VALUE1,
:new.USR_SOME_VALUE2,
:new.USR_SOME_VALUE3,
:new.USR_CREATED_DATETIME,
:new.USR_CREATED_BY,
:new.USR_SOME_VALUE4,
:new.USR_SOME_VALUE5,
v_operation,SYSDATE,v_admin_user_id);

ELSE 

   INSERT INTO SC_USR$AUD (
USR_ID,
USR_SSO_NAME,
USR_PH_NO,
USR_SIP_NAME,
USR_SIP_PSWD,
USR_SIP_DISP_NAME,
USR_CREATED_DATETIME,
USR_CREATED_BY,
USR_SIP_DOMAIN,
USR_SIP_PROXY,
aud_action,aud_timestamp,aud_user) VALUES (
:old.USR_ID,
:old.USR_SSO_NAME,
:old.USR_PH_NO,
:old.USR_SIP_NAME,
:old.USR_SIP_PSWD,
:old.USR_SIP_DISP_NAME,
:old.USR_CREATED_DATETIME,
:old.USR_CREATED_BY,
:old.USR_SIP_DOMAIN,
:old.USR_SIP_PROXY,
v_operation,SYSDATE,v_admin_user_id);

   END IF;
END;
```

As I say this works, but I don't like it for the following reasons.

1. I have to modify the connection in methods that are intended for setting up the prepared statements.
2. I have to add this code to every PreparedStatementCreator or a BatchPreparedStatementSetter object I want to audit.
3. I don't have access to the connection after the database operation so I can clear the attribute.

What I really want is a single point where I can set the attribute on the connection, before and after.

Any input or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Spring have an elegant way of doing this. The example is pretty much what you want:
[Spring Data docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.connection.html#orcl.connection.2)

Uses AOP to set the CLIENT_IDENTIFIER when a connection is got from the Datasource.

Could use another pointcut for when the connection is closed. But not a problem is the connection pool is used soley by your app.

Comment: Try here: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jdbc-ext/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/orcl.connection.html
Check your spring versions, but this link explains the Connection Preparer.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use connection labeling. Have a look at the **oracle.ucp.jdbc.LabelableConnection** interface.

Comment: Thanks for your response Steve. I've looked at the Oracle documentation "Labeling Connections in UCP" at [link](http://http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/label.htm).  I would still have to borrow the connection from the pool using the datasource getConnection(label) method, wouldn't I?  I'm not clear on how this would be different than using the Spring utility class DataSourceUtils getConnection(dataSource) method to get the connection.

Comment: It would invoked the callback and in the callback you can make sure the client identifier is always set.

Comment: If I can register a new instance of the labeling callback as each administrative user accesses the site, and I can still have Spring manage the connection, it could work.  Thanks Steve, I will give it a try and post an update.